# Swap String values without temporary variable

Tags: java, string, swap

I am aware of overflow, performance drops, etc but I need to swap two String values without any temporary variable. I know what cons are and found some effective methods but cannot understand one of them.

```
String a = "abc";
String b = "def";

b = a + (a = b).substring(0, 0);

System.out.printf("A: %s, B: %s", a, b);
```

Output shows it clear values are swapped. When I look at this seems something related with priority operations but I cannot figure it out in my mind. Please, could someone explain to me what happens?

Comment: What you want to know exactly?

Comment: What do you mean without using any temporary variable? Do you not want to see a temporary variable being used? Because I'm sure there'll always be a temporary variable that is being stored somewhere implicitely.

Comment: @skiwi It's implicitly, of course. At when dealing with immutable objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you can think on the swap operation

```
b = a + (a = b).substring(0, 0);
```

as

```
b = "abc" + (a = "def").substring(0, 0);
```

In this first step I simply substituted the variables with their values (except from the `a` in the parenthesis, since this is assigning a value, and not reading).

Now `a` is equal to `"def"` and therefore `b` is:

```
b = "abc" + "def".substring(0, 0);
```

In this step I substituted the parenthesis with its value. And now that is clearly:

```
b = "abc";
```

since the method `.substring(0, 0)` returns an empty string.

So the swap is done.

Comment: That is probably not even that inefficient, as the only temporary string that is being created is of length zero. (I assume that appending a zero-length String just returns the input).

Comment: "assume that appending a zero-length String just returns the input". Okay, probably not, as the process seems to have to involve a StringBuilder which has to copy things around.

Comment: Well, this is the answer I was looking for. Thank you @EnneCH for the explanation. I know this code is not usual coding style and it's not good practice but interviewers asks sometimes for such things.

Answer (score 0):

The fact you need to ask the question what's happening here, means you should seriously consider using constructions like this in your code.

Since in Java expressions are evaluated **left to right** (see [here](http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/ExpressionsStatements1.html) - 'Order of Evaluation' section).

This is what happens step-by-step in case of `b = a + (a = b).substring(0, 0)`

- Populate `a` variable with its value:

  `b = "abc" + (a = b).substring(0, 0);`
- Populate b variable with its value:

  `b = "abc" + (a = "def").substring(0, 0);`
- Since first attribute of string concatenation (`+`) is already evaluated evaluate the second one, which starts with reassigning `"def"` to `a`.

  `b = "abc" + "def".substring(0, 0); //Now a = "def"`
- Run `substring` on `"def"`

  `b = "abc" + ""`
- Concatenate

  `b = "abc"`
- Reassign to `b` and now b = "abc" (while as we've shown before a has been reassigned to "def".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both a and b are string variables:

```
a = (a+b).Substring((b=a).Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

public class swapping {
public static void main(String are[]) {

```
    //Swapping two Integer without temp variable 
    int a=10;
    int b=20;
    a=a+b;
    b=a-b;
    a=a-b;
    System.out.println(a+" "+b);
    
    //Swapping two string character with temp variable.
    String str1="Good";
    int as=str1.length();
    String str2="Morning";
    str1=str1+str2;
    str2=str1.substring(0, as);
    str1=str1.substring(as);
    System.out.println(str1+" "+str2);
}
```

}